# Not getting radio button value when placing ngModel

Tags: angular

Can anyone please help I am getting radio button values from backend to frontend with checked. without placing `[(ngModel)]` values are getting fine. but I want to update that getting values, for that, I used [(ngModel)]. When I placed the `[(ngModel)]` the values are not getting.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span>Please confirm that you have suitable experience and knowledge to review this article:</span>
    <div class="radio">
       <label>Yes
           <input type="radio" name="content"  [(ngModel)]="review.content"  
                                *ngIf="editUserDetails[0].content=='Yes'" value="{{review.content}}" [checked]="true">
           <input type="radio" name="content"  [(ngModel)]="review.content"  
                                *ngIf="editUserDetails[0].content=='No'" value="{{review.content}}" [checked]="false">
       </label>
       <label>No
           <input type="radio" name="content"  [(ngModel)]="review.content"  
              *ngIf="editUserDetails[0].content=='No'" value="{{review.content}}" [checked]="true">
           <input type="radio" name="content"  [(ngModel)]="review.content"  
             *ngIf="editUserDetails[0].content=='Yes'" value="{{review.content}}" [checked]="false">
       </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you make a stackblitz so we can try some code :) ?

Comment: Post your ts code with proper sample so we can run HTML and ts easily